# How to thread emails using custom headers?

Tags: c#, smtp, gmail

Does gmail preserve x-headers in email replies?
I'm developing an application which threads emails and email replies together using a Thread Id.

I add the header through SMTP .net library with the thread id, using the key X-ThreadId.

If I send it to a gmail account, I can see the header in there in the email source. However if I then reply to it, I want that header to be sent in the reply.  It seems to drop that particular header.

Does gmail drop header information in the reply email? Is this a generic problem with email? If so, how do I get round this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that Gmail **does not** add X- headers to the new email when you hit reply button.